# C++ find the second shortest path using Dijkstras algorithm?

Tags: c++, dijkstra

I have a Dijkstras algorithm program below. My program reads a text file and finds the shortest path from the start node to the goal node. My question is once this shorest path is discovered, given my code, how can I store this path? Reason being I am required to also find the second shorest path. Thankyou

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
#define INFINITY1 9999

int counter = 0;
int vcount = 0;
int ecount = 0;

int startVertex;
int endVertex;
int nVerticies;
int nEdges;

struct Vertex
{
    int label;
    int xcord;
    int ycord;
};

struct Edge
{
    int parent1;
    int parent2;
    int weight;
};

Vertex *vertArray = NULL;
Edge *edgeArray = NULL;

float distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    // Calculating distance
    return sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) +
                pow(y2 - y1, 2) * 1.0);
}

// Dijkstras
void dijkstra(vector<vector<int>> G, int n, int startnode)
{
    // Get x and y cords of start node

    int startx = vertArray[startnode].xcord;
    int starty = vertArray[startnode].ycord;

    // Get x and y cords of end node
    int endx = vertArray[n].xcord;
    int endy = vertArray[n].ycord;

    int **cost = new int *[nVerticies];
    for (int i = 0; i < nVerticies; ++i)
    {
        cost[i] = new int[nVerticies];
    }

    int distance[nVerticies], pred[nVerticies];
    int visited[nVerticies], counter, mindistance, nextnode, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < nVerticies; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < nVerticies; j++)

            // If there is no weight, then set it to infinity
            if (G[i][j] == 0)
                cost[i][j] = INFINITY1; 
            else
            {
                cost[i][j] = G[i][j];
            }
    for (i = 0; i < nVerticies; i++)
    {
        distance[i] = cost[startnode][i];
        pred[i] = startnode;
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    distance[startnode] = 0;
    visited[startnode] = 1;
    counter = 1;
    while (counter < nVerticies - 1)
    {
        mindistance = INFINITY1;
        for (i = 0; i < nVerticies; i++)
            if (distance[i] < mindistance && !visited[i])
            {
                mindistance = distance[i];
                nextnode = i;
            }
        visited[nextnode] = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < nVerticies; i++)
            if (!visited[i])
                if (mindistance + cost[nextnode][i] < distance[i])
                {
                    distance[i] = mindistance + cost[nextnode][i];
                    pred[i] = nextnode;
                }
        counter++;
    }
   for(i=n; i<n+1; i++)
        if(i!=startnode)
        {
            cout<<"\nDistance of node "<<i+1<<"="<<distance[i];
            cout<<"\nPath="<<i+1;
            j=n;
            do
            {
                j=pred[j+1];
                cout<<"<-"<<j+1;
            }
            while(j!=startnode);
        }        
}

int main()
{
    // Declaration for reading file
    int a, b, c;
    ifstream readFile;
    string fileName;

    // Ask for file name
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    readFile.open(fileName);

    // Read last line and set start and goal vertex equal to file input
    while (readFile >> startVertex >> endVertex)
    {
    }

    readFile.close();
    readFile.open(fileName);

    // Read line 1 and set nVerticies and nEdges equal to file input
    while (readFile >> nVerticies >> nEdges)
    {
        counter++;
        break;
    }

    // Create array with size nVerticies
    vertArray = new Vertex[nVerticies];
    for (int i = 0; i < nVerticies; i++)
    {
        // Initialise all elements to zero
        vertArray[i].label = 0;
        vertArray[i].xcord = 0;
        vertArray[i].ycord = 0;
    }

    // Create array with size nEdges
    edgeArray = new Edge[nEdges];
    for (int i = 0; i < nEdges; i++)
    {
        // Initialise all elements to zero
        edgeArray[i].parent1 = 0;
        edgeArray[i].parent2 = 0;
        edgeArray[i].weight = 0;
    }

    vector<vector<int>> G(nVerticies, vector<int>(nVerticies, 0));

    while (readFile >> a >> b >> c)
    {
        // Get vertex from file and add it to array
        if (nVerticies >= counter)
        {
            vertArray[vcount].label = a;
            vertArray[vcount].xcord = b;
            vertArray[vcount].ycord = c;

            vcount++;
            counter++;
        }

        // Get edge from file and add it to array
        else
        {
            G[a - 1][b - 1] = c;
            G[b - 1][a - 1] = c;
            edgeArray[ecount].parent1 = a;
            edgeArray[ecount].parent2 = b;
            edgeArray[ecount].weight = c;
            ecount++;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    readFile.close();

    dijkstra(G, endVertex - 1, startVertex - 1);

    int n = 11;
    int u = 0;
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output from read file

```
Distance of node 1=46
Path=1<-2
Distance of node 3=65
Path=3<-1<-2
Distance of node 4=47
Path=4<-2
Distance of node 5=36
Path=5<-2
Distance of node 6=53
Path=6<-2
Distance of node 7=135
Path=7<-8<-6<-2
Distance of node 8=99
Path=8<-6<-2
Distance of node 9=95
Path=9<-4<-2
Distance of node 10=82
Path=10<-2
Distance of node 11=116
Path=11<-10<-2
Distance of node 12=76
Path=12<-2
Distance of node 13=85
Path=13<-2
```

Ive been guided to follow a similar pattern to the following

```
if you have a path of 1-->2 -->3 -->4

Set 2 to max and try again
Reset 2
Set 3 to max
Reset 3
```

Comment: Sidenote. Do you really need to use `new[]` here? You leak memory since you don't `delete[]`. Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Is that the output from one call to `dijkstra()`? Also, if you sorted these manually, which would be the correct order, from the shortest to the longest path? Can you update the question to include that info?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes it is a single call. Im not sure of the full order but I do know the second shortest path should be 116 following a path node 2--> node 6-->node 13

Comment: Ok, then I suspect that your program isn't showing all the necessary information - or how would you be able to determine that from the output your program now shows?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can provide the full program its only 230 lines

Comment: It would probably not help me but if you can make it output everything needed to be able to sort it, it'd would be one step closer. Btw, the output you've listed is not complete. The `Path` part is missing from node 13.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ive just added the full program plus fixed the output

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ive been given a bit of Pseudocode as well that ive added to the bottom of the question

Comment: Ok, I don't see the pattern. Can you, if you look at that output, determine the shortest path? If so, how?

Comment: @TedLyngmo the shorest path is the final one ``` Distance of node 13=85
Path=13<-2 ```

Comment: Ok and how can I, from the output the program prints, determine that that is shorter than `Distance of node 1=46
Path=1<-2`?

Comment: Another thing: You should add the input file to the question too.